# Converting floating point numpy array to tuple

Tags: python, numpy

How can I convert floating point array in numpy to tuple

```py
arr = np.random.random(3)
```

Looking at similar posts here gave the solution:

```py
tuple(map(tuple,arr))
```

but this gives me:

```
typeerror: numpy.float64 object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` has only one dimension. `tuple(arr)` is enough in this case.